# Fetch multiples APIs si hago click en un boton

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer fecth a multiples URLs de la misma API. Tengo un array con de URLs, básicamente quiero una URL estática (trending gifs) y en caso de que se de click al botón, agregar la URL de búsqueda en el array y por lo tanto con el Fetch. Soy algo nueva en JS así que dejenme saber si hay algo que no haga sentido en el código

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="search">Search</label>
        <input id="search" type="search">
        <button id="btnSearch type="button">Go</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

.JS

```
function getAllUrls(urls) {
   return Promise.all(
        urls.map(url => fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(content => {
                console.log('[+]', content.data)
                console.log('[-]', content.meta)
            })
        )
    )
}

function init() {
    let apiKey = 'xxxx';
    let urls = [
        `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=${apiKey}&limit=20&offset=3`,
    ]

    document.getElementById('btnSearch').onclick = function() {
        let userInput = document.getElementById('search').value.trim()
        let searchUrl = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${userInput}api_key=${apiKey}&limit=20&offset=5`
        return urls.push(searchUrl)
    }

    let responses = getAllUrls(urls)
}
```

El problema base es que solo estoy recibiendo la data de los trending gifs aún si hago click en el botón o no

Comment: Hi, you are in SO spanish; please translate your question.

Comment: eso ocurre por que estas haciendo `getAllUrls(urls)` fuera de la función que detecta el click y por cierto te falta cerrar una cimilla doble en el id de tu boton :)